# Doubts about Yii2 RBAC

Tags: php, yii2, rbac

I've been developing web apps using Yii 1.1.14 so far, but now it's time for an upgrade.

The company where I work has developed its own Access Control system, and I was really OK with it until I saw what it was really like... A combination of 8 tables in the database (not counting the users table), with a bunch of foreign keys.

- 1 table for controllers
- 1 table for the  actions
- 1 table for the menu categories
- 1 table for types of users
- And the other tables basically just connect 2 or 3 of those tables at a time.

It works well, but in my point of view it's highly time consuming to maintain all those tables, and at some point, when your application goes online, if it hits a certain amount of users it could get really slow. specially because 2 of those tables have the user's table primary key as foreign key.

So I've decided that, when I start developing on Yii 2, I'm going to start using RBAC, so I started looking for tutorials online... Only finding many different versions of the same code with author's role, and permissions for create or update posts.

I found a combination of 5 videos on Youtube, but they are about Yii 1 RBAC. They were helpful because I managed to understand most of RBAC's functionality, but I still have some doubts that I'll
enumerate below. And keep in mind that for this Access Control system I'm using the **DBManager** class.

***My Doubts***

1. Yii 1's RBAC used to have 3 tables: `auth_assignment`, `auth_item` and `auth_item_child`. Now in Yii 2 RBAC, a new table appears that is called `auth_rule` and I still don't understand what that specific table is doing there, how to use it or how to populate it.
2. I see that it's possible to restrict the user's access to some actions by using the controller's behavior method, and assigning access to some actions depending on the user's role, but when it comes to this I have to split my question into 2:

   2.1. **First:** If you can just restrict the access to actions by setting it up in the behaviors method, then what's the use of saving permissions to the `auth_item` table?

   2.2. **Second:** If you DO decide to control access according to permissions, then how exactly do you do it, because I find myself writing the following type of code inside of every function and I don't think using RBAC is supposed to be this tedious. There has to be another way.

   ```
   public function actionView($id)
   {
       if(Yii::$app->user->can('view-users')){
           return $this->render('view', [
               'model' => $this->findModel($id),
           ]);
       }else{
           #Redirect to a custom made action that will show a view 
           #with a custom error message
           $this->redirect(['//site/notauthorized']);
       }
   }
   ```
3. Because of the Access Control System that we use right now, when a user logs in, a complex query is executed that will end up returning an array that will be saved as a session variable, and will be used to create a menu with as many dropdownlists as menu categories, that the controllers that the user has access to belong to. How can this be done with RBAC?

Answer (score 2):

I can only really answer 2.2 of your question, as 3 doesn't sound at all like something an RBAC should do.  You could, however, get the information you needed from the rules table most likely, provided you followed a naming convention that matched your controllers or actions.

On to answering 2.2 though:

You can simply set the behavior like such:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'actions' => ['view'],
                    'roles' => ['view-users'], //<-- Note, rule instead of role
                ],
        ]
    ]
}
```

This doesn't solve a different problem of 'view-own-users' style permissions, as this needs to inspect the ActiveRecord model (well, at least it does in my application).  If  You want to achieve this, take a look at my post in the Yii forums here:

http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/60439-yii2-rbac-permissions-in-controller-behaviors/#entry269913

Answer (score 1):

I use it in one of the simplest method,I use them in the behaviours of my controller.

```
 public function behaviors()
    {

        return [
            'access' => [
                'class' => \yii\filters\AccessControl::className(),
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['sysadmin'],
                        'actions' => ['index','view','update'],
                    ],
                    [
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['staff'],
                        'actions' => ['index','create','update','view'],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];

    }
```

Here roles are the one created in the auth-item table in the database and they have been assigned for users in auth-assignment table. In the behaviours we just use it as above. In the above code sysadmin can have access to index, view and update action, whereas staff can have access to index,create, update and view action.

Answer (score 0):

Yii2 needs a little setup when it comes to using RBAC under your controllers AccessControl. I got around it by making my own AccessRule file.

```
namespace app\components;

use Yii;

class AccessRule extends \yii\filters\AccessRule
{
    protected function matchRole($user)
    {
        if (empty($this->roles)) {
            return true;
        }
        foreach ($this->roles as $role) {
            if(Yii::$app->authManager->checkAccess($user->identity->code, $role))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
}
```

then in your controller u can use something like this:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'ruleConfig' => [
                'class' => 'app\components\AccessRule'
            ],
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'actions' => ['index', 'resource-type'],
                    'allow'=> true,
                    'roles' => ['admin'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

Where admin is defined as a auth_item and the user is in the auth_item_assignments.

Answer (score 0):

As I have created a new Rbac system for yii2. you can direct permission for a action and action will show you are not authorisez for this action.

By this you find that you will only provide access for action that need to identify.

I uploaded my detail here you can find lot of solution [here](http://usourcecode.com/articles/view/role-base-management-system-in-yii2-user).

Comment: You should write the relevant portion of the answer here, not just link to some resource.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best solution i could come up with when facing the need to filter access by permissions, it's bothersome but can be useful if you're trying to create roles in a productive enviroment and want to use rbac.

```
use yii\web\ForbiddenHttpException;


if(Yii::$app->user->can('view-users')){
    return $this->render('view', [
        'model' => $this->findModel($id),
    ]);
}else{
    throw new ForbiddenHttpException('You dont have access to this site');
}
```