# How to add use RBAC rule to control access to controller action?

Tags: yii2

I setting up a new Yii 2.0 project, and I am trying to use RBAC to control access to certain controller actions.  I am using DbManager.  How do I set up the rules array at the top of the controller class to control access to the actions?

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-filters-accessrule.html#$roles-detail

Comment: I found a Stackoverflow answer that answers my question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26752495/doubts-about-yii2-rbac/26938699

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tipically in controller yon can add your rule in this way

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'actions' => ['index','view'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['viewer', 'viewerModel1', 'viewerModel2'],
                ],
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['superAdmin', 'admin', 'manage', 'managerModel1', 'managerModel2'],
                ],   
            ],
        ],        
        'verbs' => [
            'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
            'actions' => [
                'delete' => ['post'],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

this rule permit access to index and view  for `'viewer', 'viewerModel1', 'viewerModel2'` . All access for management to `'superAdmin', 'admin', 'manage', 'managerModel1', 'managerModel2'`  in this way other role cna't access to views application for this controller